# Finding the matrix representation of a linear transformation[Confusion]

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

In my book I have the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the basis is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

$$T \begin{pmatrix}a  \\b  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3a -    b\\ a + 3b \end{pmatrix}$$

So I put in the vectors 
$ \begin{pmatrix}1  \\0  \end{pmatrix} $ and $ \begin{pmatrix}0  \\1  \end{pmatrix} $ inside $T$ to get:

$$T \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$T \begin{pmatrix}0  \\1  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1\\ \ 3\end{pmatrix}$$

and I get
$$ [T]_{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}3 &-1\\ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$$

but my book says
$$ [T]_{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}3 &1\\ -1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}.$$

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are right, because $T(1,0)=(3,1)$ and $T(0,1)=(-1,3)$ which are the columns of your matrix.

Comment: @HectorBlandin then the books wrong? I'm still confused.

Comment: Your first equation, with two "$=$" signs in it doesn't make much sense. Why would $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3a-b\\a+3b\end{pmatrix}$ hold? And how is $T$ "equal" to both of them, if $T$ is a transformation, not a vector? Other than that, your answer seems right. Either there's a typo in the answers in the book (which happens), or you've misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @Temirzhan: Yes, you right. Is just a typo error in the book.

Comment: @Temirzhan Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

$$T \begin{pmatrix}a  \\b  \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}x & y\\ z&w\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a  \\b  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ax +by\\ az + bw \end{pmatrix}$$

thus you are right!